# requests.post зависает на моменте подключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, requests

Возможно у меня действительно кривые руки, но при попытке отправить запрос на сайт "api.vk.com" программа зависает на моменте рукопожатия (do_handshake) либо на моменте подключения для отправки сокета (sock.connect). Причем это не ошибка сети - отправка запроса на yandex.ru прошла успешно. Я гуглил, да нагуглил, нужно отключить IPv6 в свойствах адаптера - не помогло. Есть способы решения?

P.S. У меня Windows 8.1 Pro x64, Питон 3.

P.P.S. программа работала где-то месяц, потом перестала.

Comment: проверьте, не полменялось ли API за это время. Перепрочитайте документацию. Возможно что-то изменилось

Comment: @cauf ничего не поменялось. все еще https, все еще api.vk.com/method/названиеметода

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация. Помогает установить таймаут (при этом он не будет падать на нем а нормально отрабатывать). Но это не решение. Либки использующие реквестс (shodan) будут также висеть и таймаут не выставишь. Удалось разобраться в чем дело ?

Comment: Мне помогло отключить ipv6
Из этого ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885446/python-requests-module-hangs-on-socket-connection-but-curl-works

Comment: @ВладиславоаоаоаПрачик, по ссылке только для линукса ответ? У автора вопроса виндовс